# Dynamic filter code in Selenium using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have an Ui where there is a dynamic filter present.
I need to check the functionality of the filter by entering any input value,but here the issue is the result is not constant from where i can search.

This is the HTML body of the filter:
`<label>
Filter: 
<input class="" type="search" placeholder="" aria-controls="revtable"/>
</label>
</div>`

And also i need to verify that the filter is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly grab a collection of elements and do a quick check to see if the element exist. Notice if you have element loading issue then some other mechanism needs to be used to confirm element load.

```
//Make sure the selector is written precisely. 
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[aria-controls='revtable']"));
if (elements.size()>0){
    //we know element present
    //I am grabbing first item on the list
    elements.get(0).sendKeys("Test");
}else{
    //element does not exist
}
```